# Linkedin apply button plugin not logging in on IE8

Tags: plugins, linkedin-api

I asked this on the linkedin forum a few days ago, but no response there and nothing in a general web search, so trying here.

i I have an apply button test page at http://solomon.ie/li/ (HTML below also).

On IE8/WinXP if I hit apply, while not logged into my Linkedin account, I get the sign in screen/lightbox, hit Sign in button, get the login form popup, enter my details and the screen flashes. But, instead of getting my profile summary and confirm application , I am back to the the sign in screen/lightbox.

If I am already logged in and hit apply it works as normal. Works fine on IE9 and FF and Chrome.

I reset IE8 to default security settings and cleared cache/cookies. No error messages.

Thanks,
Kevin

--

```
<html>
<head>
<title> New Document </title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
api_key: dhap7citpirm
</script>

<h1>solomon test job ie</h1>

<script type="IN/Apply" data-companyid="892056" data-jobId="Cj-222234"
data-jobtitle="Test job 4"
data-jobLocation="Dublin Ireland"
data-questions='[{"question": "Can you drive?"},{"question": "Do you have a SAFEPASS?"}]'
data-email="nospam@gmail.com"></script>

</body>
</html>
```